# React Native Export Whole Content of Scroll View into PDF

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a react-native project and I am facing the following problem:

I have a ScrollView with dynamic size. I would like to be able to export the content of the ScrollView into a PDF on click of a button. It is like creating a screenshot that scrolls through my whole view before saving the image into a pdf. How can I achieve that ?

I know that there is a component called "react-pdf" that I can use to render my own pdf. Is this the way to go ?
I have also seen that there is a component called "react-native-view-shot" which takes a picture of a view. But in my case it is a ScrollView so I don't think that it will work

Comment: Hey, Have you found the solution??